# Error de conexión con SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server

Tengo 2 servidores en la misma red. Un servidor Linux, en el que está alojado la página web, y un servidor Windows en el cual está en SQL Server 2012.

Quiero establecer una conexión desde Linux hacia el SQL. Para ello, he creado un archivo en el servidor web:

**test.php**

```
<?php
$con = sqlsrv_connect('192.168.9.10:1433','sa','contraseña','logytel');
if ($con) {
    echo "Conexión establecida.<br>";
}else{
    echo "La conexión no se pudo establecer.<br>";
    die( print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

Un archivo sencillo para comprobar si conecta, pero no. Al intentar acceder mediante localhost/test.php, me sale una pantalla en blanco indicando el error 500.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

El SQL Server tiene activado el protocolo TCP/IP, los puertos están abiertos, estoy usando la cuenta "sa" del Sql Server que se supone que es la que se usa para conexiones remotas, tiene excepciones en el firewall, el puerto es el predeterminado, 1433.
Por las dudas, también instalé el controlador de PHP en el servidor Windows.

Comment: Puede que no tengas instalado y/o activado el conector para SQL Server. Puedes lanzar un `phpinfo();` desde un archivo simple y verificar si los controladores están instalados o no.

Comment: ¿ Podrías editar de nuevo la pregunta añadiendo los resultados del siguiente código PHP ? ```php <?php echo " ¿Cargado módulo  sqlsrv ? . (extension_loaded('sqlsrv') ? "Si" : "No");
echo " ¿ Cargado móudlo pdo_sqlsrv ? " . (extension_loaded('pdo_sqlsrv') ? "Si" : "No");  ```

Comment: @A.Cedano he lanzado ese comando, parece que están instalados, aunque no estoy 100% segura. Añado a la pregunta imágenes

Comment: Ten cuidado, no vayas a subir imágenes aquí con información sensible. En la página que muestra la configuración busca este tèrmino `sqlsrv` y si quieres edita la pregunta poniendo lo que dice al respecto. Eso es lo único que interesa ver.

Comment: En la imagen no parece que los controladores de SQL Server estén instalados. De todos modos, busca este término **`sqlsrv`** puede que tengas los `.dll`, pero que no esté activado.

Comment: No aparece ningún resultado con `sqlsrv`

Comment: Pues eso, tienes que instalarlo en tu entorno Linux. [Aquí tienes la guía oficial de Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-ver15) que explica paso a paso cómo hacer y lo que hay que descargar. Observa siempre el tipo de archivo que debes descargar según tu versión de Sistema Operativo, de PHP y de Base de Datos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con esto se soluciona el error 500

```
$serverName = '192.168.9.10, 1433';
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"logytel", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"contraseña");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if ($conn) {
    echo "Conexión establecida.<br>";
}else{
    echo "La conexión no se pudo establecer.<br>";
    die( print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Simplemente debes comprobar que los datos de la "Database", "UID" y "PWD" son correctos y se te conectará

Comment: Acabo de probarlo, el error sigue apareciendo

Comment: Comprueba que tienes instalados los .dll del sqlsrv correctamente, ya que en mi pc, al comprobar el código el error 500 no aparece

Comment: Como puedo comprobarlo?

Comment: En el php info debes ver que versión de php tienes y tambien si tienes el Thread-safe, apartir de eso, en la carpeta php, donde tienes las .dll del sqlsrv comprueba con la tabla de https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/connect/php/system-requirements-for-the-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-ver15 donde verás que versión tienes que tener instalada

Comment: Añado también, que en el archivo php.ini debes tener las exclusiones sqlsrv activadas, si no, por mucho que estén los archivos .dll no va a funcionar